# Domain to VPS Setup

Tags: domain, ubuntu-14.04, vps

I have a VPS through A Small Orange that has 3 IP addresses and I have Vesta Control Panel installed to manage the sites. It should also (I believe) have two nameservers with A Small Orange at ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com

I am wanting to add another site to this setup with a domain I have registered at namecheap, lets call it domaintwo.com. Right now the site has its own IP and the domain has some records pointing to that IP. I am not sure if this is the best solution as email both in an out is not working.

I've done a lot of research every which way but I just haven't quite hit the nail on the head; however it has made me fairly comfortable modifying records, etc.

What then is the best way to connect my new domain with my existing setup or other possible ways that could get the same result? Or if there are any wonderful resources I would be happy to look them over. I would through the process like to understand what I"m doing and why.

Thank you so much if you can help.

Answer (score 2):

Namecheap offers DNS, you can set your IP of the server to an A record in there control panel

Regarding your email you can setup MX records too. Though in the server configuration you may need to allow this new hostname.

[image]

Please note, DNS can take up to a day to be active. You also may need to flush your local DNS cache to test quickly.